# Upload Youtube using Proxy, per connection and not system wide

Tags: youtube-api

I have a Java code using youtube-api to upload videos. Until now I was using the system configuration to set the proxy (http and https) and everything is working fine that way. But now I have a new requirement regarding the way we use proxy on the server. As we have other services running on the very same server, they asked me to not configure the proxy using system wide approach, because this affect all the services using JVM.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", httpProxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", httpProxyPort);
```

and

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", httpsProxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", httpsProxyPort);
```

I have spent the last couple days researching that on the Internet and didn't find anything useful. I found a explanation on the C# API what seems to be setting the proxy to the connection and I didn't find a way to implement this same approach on Java.

I want to do something like this:

```
service = new YouTubeService(APPLICATION_NAME, DEVELOPER_KEY);
service.setUserCredentials(userName, password);
uploader = new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(
        service, new URL(RESUMABLE_UPLOAD_URL), ms, newVideoEntry)
            .title(videoTitle)
            .trackProgress(listener, PROGRESS_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .chunkSize(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE).build();

// fictional code to show what I want to do
uploader.setProxyHttp(httpProxyHost, httpProxyPort);
uploader.setProxyHttps(httpsProxyHost, httpsProxyPort);

uploader.start();
```

This is very similar to what Java already allow us to do. See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved with the following code. Adapt the method `setPersonalUrlConnectionFactory` to set your proxy and call it passing as argument your uploader.

```
package com.google.gdata.client.uploader;

import com.google.gdata.client.media.ResumableGDataFileUploader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PersonalUrlConnectionInjector {

    public static void setPersonalUrlConnectionFactory(ResumableGDataFileUploader uploader) {
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field field = uploader.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("urlConnectionFactory");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            java.lang.reflect.Field modifiersField = java.lang.reflect.Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~java.lang.reflect.Modifier.FINAL);

            field.set(uploader, new UrlConnectionFactory() {
                @Override
                public HttpURLConnection create(URL url) throws IOException {
                    return new sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection(url, MY_PROXY);
                }
            }); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* DO LOG */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not working on this anymore, if someone used this solution with success, please, let me know and I will mark the answer as accepted.